# How to filter a dataframe wrt to a particular value range of a column using R?

Tags: r, rstudio, data-cleaning

```
input<-read. csv("aggregate. csv")
```

The csv looks like:

```
TimeStamp        Latency     Threads
7:00.06 AM            20               19
7:00.09 AM            28               18
7:00.15 AM            26               19
7:04:51 AM            45               20
7:05.07 AM            05               23
7:00.25 AM            15               24
7:10.01 AM            24               25
7:20.01 AM            35               50
8:00:10 AM            05               51
8:00:52 AM            50               10
8:05:00 AM            12               09
8:10:00 AM           100               01
```

But the problem I am facing is I want to filter out the input dataframe by giving user input as `TimeStamp` column. Means the console should ask`Enter your time range`

Suppose If I enter bw 7:00:01 AM to 7:05:00 AM. then it should filter the dataframe according to that.
The output should be like..

```
TimeStamp        Latency     Threads
7:00.06 AM            20               19
7:00.09 AM            28               18
7:00.15 AM            26               19
7:04:51 AM            45               20
```

Is it possible? 
I posted here because filtering it was getting hard-coded but I want that to be user input.

Please help

Comment: see `?readLine`

Comment: Tried but it did not work..

Comment: Can u be more specific.. I tried it prompts the User to give input but then how to filter the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can try `strptime` function. It will transfer a character into a POSIXlt object, which is a Date-Time Classes. After the transformation, you can compare the times by `time 1 < time 2`, etc. You can find more details by `?strptime`.

One more thing bothering is that your TimeStamp column has multiple formats: `7:00.06 AM` and `7:04:51 AM`. You probably need to pre-process the format by `gsub`

Suppose you got your input range is from `lower` to `upper`, then

```
input <- read.csv("C:/Users/s0043102/Desktop/test.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
adj_TimeStamp <- gsub("\\.",":",input$TimeStamp)
adj_TimeStamp <- strptime(adj_TimeStamp ,format="%H:%M:%S %p")
lower <-  strptime("7:00:01 AM",format="%H:%M:%S %p")
upper <-  strptime("7:05:00 AM",format="%H:%M:%S %p")
output <- subset(input, adj_TimeStamp<=upper & adj_TimeStamp>=lower)
output

    TimeStamp Latency Threads
 1 7:00.06 AM      20      19
 2 7:00.09 AM      28      18
 3 7:00.15 AM      26      19
 4 7:04:51 AM      45      20
 6 7:00.25 AM      15      24
```

Comment: I skipped the part to get input because it seems that you have already figured it out from comments.